# Genetic Algorithm Elitism Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, genetic-algorithm

I'm trying to do the elitism method to get the best fitness value of each of the generations I generate, keeping beyond the fitness the values ​​of X and Y to be an individual of the next generation, however, I can't apply a logic using dict that Solve the problem. It remains to get this detail right to be able to finalize the complete implementation and carry out the general revisions.

```
import random

def generate_population(size, x_boundaries, y_boundaries):
    lower_x_boundary, upper_x_boundary = x_boundaries
    lower_y_boundary, upper_y_boundary = y_boundaries

    population = []
    for i in range(size):
        individual = {
            'x': random.uniform(lower_x_boundary, upper_x_boundary),
            'y': random.uniform(lower_y_boundary, upper_y_boundary),
        }
        population.append(individual)

    return population

def fitness(individual):
    x = individual['x']
    y = individual['y']
    
    return abs((-(100*(x*x - y)*(x*x - y) + (1 - x)*(1-x))))

def sort_population_by_fitness(population):
    return sorted(population, key=fitness)
    
def choice_by_roulette(sorted_population, fitness_sum):
    drawn = random.uniform(0, 1)
    accumulated = 0
    
    for individual in sorted_population:
        fitnessX = fitness(individual)
        probability = fitnessX / fitness_sum
        accumulated += probability
        
        if drawn <= accumulated:
            return individual
        
def crossover(choice_a, choice_b):
    xa = choice_a['x']
    ya = choice_a['y']
    
    xb = choice_b['x'] 
    yb = choice_b['y'] 
    
    #xa = xa*xb
    #xa = xa**0.5
    
    #ya = ya*yb
    #ya = ya**0.5
    
    
    return {'x': xa+0.01, 'y': ya+0.01}      

def mutate(new_individual):
    
    x = new_individual['x']
    y = new_individual['y']
    
    flagx = 0
    flagy = 0
    
    new_x = x*(1+random.uniform(-0.01/2, 0.01/2))
    new_y = y*(1+random.uniform(-0.01/2, 0.01/2))
    
    while flagx == 1:
        if (new_x > 2) or (new_x < -2):
            new_x = x*(1+random.uniform(-0.01/2, 0.01/2))
            flagx = 1
        else:
            flagx = 0
    
    while flagy == 1:
        if (new_y > 2) or (new_y < -2):
            new_y = y*(1+random.uniform(-0.01/2, 0.01/2))
            flagy = 1
        else:
            flagy = 0
    return {'x': new_x, 'y': new_y}
    
def eletism(x_gen, milior):
    pior = sort_population_by_fitness(x_gen)

    fitness(pior)
    
    print(pior)

    #for i in x_gen:
        #print(teste['x'])
        #x = teste['x']
        #y = teste['y']
    
    #print(milior)
    return pior

def make_next_gen(population):
    next_gen = []
    
    sorted_population = sort_population_by_fitness(population)
    soma_fitness = sum(fitness(individual)for individual in population)
    
    for i in range(9):
        first_choice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_population, soma_fitness)
        second_choice = choice_by_roulette(sorted_population, soma_fitness)
        
        new_individual = crossover(first_choice, second_choice)
        
        drawn = random.randint(1,5)
        
        if drawn == 1:
            new_individual = mutate(new_individual)
        next_gen.append(new_individual)
    
    return next_gen
        
generations = 100

population = generate_population(size=10, x_boundaries=(-2, 2), y_boundaries=(-2, 2))

i = 0
while i!= generations:
    for individual in population:
        print(individual, fitness(individual))
    
    population = make_next_gen(population)

    i += 1

best_individual = sort_population_by_fitness(population)[-1]
print(best_individual, fitness(best_individual))
```